# Swipe one item at a time vertically in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

How can implement one item swipe at a time in recycler view like viewpager vertically .I am used SnapHelper also but did not get proper result.Please help me.Used this dependency in android compile : 
'com.allattentionhere:autoplayvideos:0.0.9'. My Code is below......

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.rv_home)
    AAH_CustomRecyclerView recyclerView;
    private final List<MyModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Picasso p = Picasso.with(this);
//        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://www.betcoingaming.com/webdesigns/animatedslider/images/liveroulette2.mp4","http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.jpg","name1"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.jpg", "video1"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1491561340/hello_cuwgcb.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1491561340/hello_cuwgcb.jpg", "video2"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795675/3_yqeudi.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795675/3_yqeudi.jpg", "video4"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795675/1_pyn1fm.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795675/1_pyn1fm.jpg", "video5"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1491561340/hello_cuwgcb.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1491561340/hello_cuwgcb.jpg", "video6"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.jpg", "video9"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795676/4_nvnzry.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795676/4_nvnzry.jpg", "video11"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.jpg", "video12"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795675/3_yqeudi.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795675/3_yqeudi.jpg", "video16"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795675/1_pyn1fm.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795675/1_pyn1fm.jpg", "video17"));
        modelList.add(new MyModel("http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.mp4", "http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.jpg", "video18"));
        //you can pass local file uri, but make sure it exists
//        modelList.add(new MyModel("/storage/emulated/0/VideoPlay/myvideo.mp4","http://res.cloudinary.com/krupen/video/upload/w_300,h_150,c_crop,q_70,so_0/v1481795681/2_rp0zyy.jpg","video18"));

        MyVideosAdapter mAdapter = new MyVideosAdapter(modelList, p);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        /*  SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);*/

        //todo before setAdapter
        recyclerView.setActivity(this);
        //optional - to play only first visible video
        recyclerView.setPlayOnlyFirstVideo(true); // false by default
        //optional - download videos to local storage (requires "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in manifest or ask in runtime)
        recyclerView.setDownloadPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyVideo"); // (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Video") by default
        recyclerView.setDownloadVideos(true); // false by default
        //extra - start downloading all videos in background before loading RecyclerView
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MyModel object : modelList) {
            if (object.getVideo_url() != null && object.getVideo_url().endsWith(".mp4"))
                urls.add(object.getVideo_url());
        }
        recyclerView.preDownload(urls);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //to init videos before scrolling
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, 1);
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, -1);
    }
}




public class MyVideosAdapter extends AAH_VideosAdapter {
    private final List<MyModel> list;
    private final Picasso picasso;
    public class MyViewHolder extends AAH_CustomViewHolder {
        // final TextView tv;
        final ImageView img_vol;
        //to mute/un-mute video (optional)
        boolean isMuted;
        public MyViewHolder(View x) {
            super(x);
            //tv = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.tv);
            img_vol = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.img_vol);
        }
    }

    public MyVideosAdapter(List<MyModel> list_urls, Picasso p) {
        this.list = list_urls;
        this.picasso = p;
    }

    @Override
    public AAH_CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AAH_CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //((MyViewHolder) holder).tv.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        //todo
        holder.setImageUrl(list.get(position).getImage_url());
        holder.setVideoUrl(list.get(position).getVideo_url());
        //load image into imageview
        if (list.get(position).getImage_url() != null && !list.get(position).getImage_url().isEmpty()) {
            picasso.load(holder.getImageUrl()).config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(holder.getAAH_ImageView());
        }
        //to mute/un-mute video (optional)
        holder.getAah_vi().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((MyViewHolder) holder).isMuted) {
                    holder.unmuteVideo();
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unmute);
                } else {
                    holder.muteVideo();
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mute);
                }
                ((MyViewHolder) holder).isMuted = !((MyViewHolder) holder).isMuted;
            }
        });

        if (list.get(position).getVideo_url() == null) {
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}


And used this dependency in android compile
```

'com.allattentionhere:autoplayvideos:0.0.9'

Comment: make height and width of "single_card" match parent, so recycleview will show single item at a time.

Comment: Thanks for replay.Actually i am need effect like viewPager.

Comment: Then i don't think recycleview is a way to go. You should be implementing vertical viewpager and also look at Viewpager.pageTransform for the vertical effect.

Comment: I solved used PagerSnapHelper which is in v7 support Library.

Answer (score 1):

To just scroll only one item at a time use pager snap helper instead of linear

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach Your Recyclerview to this piece of code, and it will work like a charm :)

```
 SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
 snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```